# How to configure aws-sdk in Angular 7

Tags: node.js, angular

When I do

```
npm install  aws-sdk
```

in Angular 7, I get an error

> Error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
>
> Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try npm i @types/node

and even though I do run `install  npm i @types/node`, I am still getting the same error:

[image: even though i install npm i @types/node i am getting same error]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To resolve this issue, you can try to add in your `tsconfig.app.json` the following line:

```
"types": ["node"]
```

Angular is complaining because some node environment types are needed.

Answer (score 4):

Please modify your files as follows:

```
// aws-sdk requires global to exist
(window as any).global = window;
```

to **/src/polyfills.ts**
and

```
"types": ["node"]
```

to **compilerOptions** block in **/src/tsconfig.app.json**

credit to: [afaneh262](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2141#issuecomment-434673824)

Comment: This worked fantastically, the important step was `(window as any).global = window;`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a change in **tsconfig.app.json** file first inside compilerOptions as follows:

```
"types": ["node"]
```

After that, add a code in **polyfills.js** file. Otherwise you will get an error later (ReferenceError: global is not defined). Here is the code:

```
(window as any).global = window;
```